# nest API 5.3 [Elasticproperty]

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying out the new .netapi for elasticsearch nest version 5.3 but I am not able to declare the property type like as

```
[ElasticProperty(Name = "sys_updated_on", Store = true, Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Type = FieldType.Date)
  public DateTimeOffset sys_updated_on { get; set; }
```

how to declare this in the new nest version 5.3. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ElasticPropertyAttribute` was deprecated in NEST 2.0+ in favour of type specific attributes.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/nest-breaking-changes.html#_attribute_based_mapping) In this case, the replacement would be

```
[Date(Name = "sys_updated_on", Store = true)]
public DateTimeOffset sys_updated_on { get; set; }
```

A few points

1. `Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed` is not valid on `Date` (one reason why the attributes were split out into separate types); it's either indexed or not and is represented as a `bool` in the attribute mapping
2. If you're indexing with the name `"sys_updated_on"`, you can use an idiomatic .NET property name e.g. `SysUpdatedOn`.
3. Unless you need to retrieve the field separately using [`stored_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fields-usage.html), the original value will be stored and be retrievable from `_source`, so don't need to use `Store = true`